# Iteration in PHP dynamic variable

Tags: php

```
function stepzero(){
    $alcount = $_POST["alcount"];//retrieve number of row
    $crcount = $_POST["crcount"];//retrieve number of coloumn

    for ($x=1; $x <=$crcount ; $x++) { //Loop for coloumn
        for ($y=1; $y <=$alcount ; $y++) { //Loop for row
            ${"v".$y."t".$x} = $_POST["r".$y."c".$x];//retrieve value of table
            ${"v".$y."t".$x} = ${"v".$y."t".$x}*${"v".$y."t".$x};//square the value
            ${"nv".$y."t".$x} = ${"nv".$y."t".$x} + ${"v".$y."t".$x}; //not working
            echo ${"nv".$y."t".$x};
            echo "<br>";
        }
    }
}
```

I have this function to retrieve value from table , square it and then sum it. But `${"nv".$y."t".$x}`   returns the same value as `${"v".$y."t".$x}` (it didn't sum it). How can I fix this?

Comment: arrays are a million times easier to work with than variable variables

Comment: In your code ${"nv".$y."t".$x} = ${"nv".$y."t".$x} + ${"v".$y."t".$x}; Is similar to ${"nv".$y."t".$x} = 0 + ${"v".$y."t".$x}; And that's why it returns similar values.

Comment: This is insane. Use an array.

Comment: i think if you run that you end up being sent to: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ

Comment: It's not fair to vote this question down just because he's doing it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

This code could be a lot simpler.

For example, these two lines:

```
${"v".$y."t".$x} = ${"v".$y."t".$x}*${"v".$y."t".$x};//square the value
${"nv".$y."t".$x} = ${"nv".$y."t".$x} + ${"v".$y."t".$x}; //not working
```

Could be better written as:

```
${"v".$y."t".$x} *= ${"v".$y."t".$x};//square the value
${"nv".$y."t".$x} += ${"v".$y."t".$x}; //not working
```

Comment: OK, in doing so, you might notice that ${"nv".$y."t".$x} is a new variable for each iteration of the loop. So, when you add ${"v".$y."t".$x} to it, you are really just adding ${"v".$y."t".$x} to zero. Are you trying to sum it all up?

Comment: Yes, i'm trying to sum it all but save all of the iteration. Now i'm trying to make a global array then insert every ${"v".$y."t".$x} by using the loop. Then i will sum it using foreach(). Is this right?

Comment: Now that I understand what you're up to, I've posted a different answer. I think it's what you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to get the sum of the squares of a bunch of values, try this:

```
function stepzero(){
    $alcount = $_POST["alcount"];//retrieve number of row
    $crcount = $_POST["crcount"];//retrieve number of coloumn
    $sum = 0;

    for ($x=1; $x <=$crcount ; $x++) { //Loop for coloumn
        for ($y=1; $y <=$alcount ; $y++) { //Loop for row
            $sum += $_POST["r".$y."c".$x] * $_POST["r".$y."c".$x];
        }
    }

    return $sum;
}
```